# Turn laptop display into normal monitor for use with a kvm in a server rack

Tags: display, kvm-switch

Like many places, we have a rack with a space for a KVM.  Also like many places, the monitor that sits there is a small ancient CRT.  I'd like to replace it with an lcd, but I don't have much chance of getting that approved in the budget, and even if I could there's other things more pressing that could use the money.  But we do end up with a dead laptop from time to time, and when that happens there's generally nothing wrong with the display.  So as something to do in my spare time, I was wondering what it would take to attach a standard vga or even dvi connector to one of these.  I'm not talking about using the whole laptop, just the display.

Comment: If people think this would do better at superuser, please feel free to  vote to move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm... There was a similar [**question**](https://superuser.com/questions/92004/use-an-old-laptop-as-a-monitor) in Superuser.com.  Unfortunately, not a good answer.  Googling (when I was curious about it) I recall just finding people who had spent an awful amount of time on it, plus having to purchase other equipment to get get it to work (costing more than $50, not including time/labor).  It's a good project, though IMHO I think there are better projects to do own your own time.  Really buying a new LCD (from craigslist/ebay or at your local tech store might be cheaper at the end, plus freeing some space on your Rack is also worth something).

Answer (score 1):

Laptop displays use not very standard variants of LVDS signaling. It is not compatible with DVI or VGA.

Comment: There is thread about same problem http://www.overclockers.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-181128.html
Some LCD controllers (digital signal converters) exist, but are very expensive (200-300$)

Comment: Also, there is a success story http://www.instructables.com/id/Laptop-Converted-to-2nd-Monitor/

Comment: That success story is cheating. He uses a vnc-like application to extend the monitor over the LAN.