# Use laptop A's LCD as secondary monitor for laptop B

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer)

I have a working laptop (laptop A), but am interested in using the laptop's LCD as a secondary monitor for my main laptop (laptop B)...is there a way to do this via software or cabling *without* modifying laptop A?  OS's are Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7.

Update:  Software must be free, and a bonus if I can switch between using Laptop A as a secondary monitor and its regular desktop.

Comment: take a look at [x2vnc](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/x2vnc.html) and [win2vnc](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/win2vnc.html).  i just ran across them today, so i don't know for sure, but it sounds like that will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are options to make this happen:  Here's a similar question with some ideas:  [Use an old laptop as a monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/92004/use-an-old-laptop-as-a-monitor)

Comment: @BBlake, MaxiVista is not free, and ZoneOS looks interesting...however, ZoneOS does not seem to be compatible with Win7 quite yet...