# How can I extend my laptop screen to the screen of a second laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer)

I have a spare laptop and I'd like to use it as a second monitor for my laptop.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Perhaps if you got a (male-male or maybe it's female-female?) video cable and plugged the output of the primary laptop into the input of the "slave"?

I think I've seen software for this before.

I see at least one solution:
http://www.maxivista.com/  ($40)

Comment: Duplicate, see http://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer

Comment: @th3due19 - nice idea editing the post, but when it does get closes this information will be added by the system so it'll be duplicated.

Comment: @th3dude19 Please don't edit duplicate links into posts. It causes double work when closing the question, as it now needs to be edited and gets bumped to the home page.

Comment: @Diago and @ChrisF - I actually had no idea that was done by the system. I had seen it done it other dupes and figured I'd help out. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[ZoneScreen](http://www.zoneos.com/zonescreen.htm)** 'might' work with Vista if you follow the workaround posted on their website.

> **Windows Vista and Windows 7 Limitations**
>
> These operating systems have two
>   important limitations affecting
>   ZoneScreen display driver. First, due
>   to Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM)
>   architecture, ZoneScreen virtual
>   display driver can't run **unless
>   leagcy XP drivers are installed on
>   main video adapter**. Also, for
>   Windows Vista x64 and Windows 7 x64
>   digital signature enforcement for
>   kernel drivers is also applied
>   (ZoneScreen driver do have
>   authenticode signature but appropriate
>   digital certificate costs a lot). So,
>   virtual display driver is not loaded
>   unless this enforcement is disabled.

Comment: The 'correct answer' on the duplicate question lists this as the answer. How about closing this as a duplicate instead of going for points :)

Comment: @th3dude19 - the other thread is dealing with the issue in general, here it's about a specific OS, and none of the limitations regarding ZoneScreen and Vista/7 is dealt with accordingly, so it's not that easy ...

Comment: @Molly - No worries, was mainly joking, but you have a good point.