# How to setup a Linux machine to remotely use laptop screen as a second display?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, remote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer)

I am looking for a similar solution to MaxiVista, but for Linux (Ubuntu). I have an Ubuntu machine with just one display attached, but I also have a Windows laptop running a virtual machine with Ubuntu installed. I figured there must be a way to trick the main Ubuntu machine remotely use the virtual machine's display capabilities. After all, X11 does support forwarding and things like that.

Any ideas how to do it using VNC?

I saw some references to xdmx, but instructions so far are vague and do not seem to work on my  machine(s).

Comment: i know the duplicate has Windows-specific answers, but the question itself is unspecific.  please place answers to this question there.

Comment: Yes, that question is Windows-specific, which is exactly why my question is different. Answer to that question will never be even close to mine!