# How to setup a Linux machine to remotely use laptop screen as a second display?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, linux-mint, remote

I would like to reopen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/151716/how-to-setup-a-linux-machine-to-remotely-use-laptop-screen-as-a-second-display?lq=1) question, because it is NOT a duplicate of [that](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer) question. I am using Kubuntu 12.10, or Mint 14 - any of these two will do. [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) offers similar functionality, but does not allow me to move a window from one screen to the other. Is there any way to get a fully transparent connection to a monitor via LAN?

Comment: [XDMX](http://www.google.com/search?q=XDMX) would let you combine both displays into a single screen.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I have been looking for. Is there some simple up-to-date tutorial? I have some issues getting it working.