# Can I use a laptop as Second monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer)

I want to try and use a monitor as a second monitor without paying for any software. Is this possible?

Someone told me me it is apparently possible using a double male usb cable. Is he correct?

I am running windows 7 on both laptops.

Answer (score 3):

win2vnc + vnc is cleaner and less buggy...  Just google win2vnc.  Full instructions should be easy to find

Comment: why the downvote, people?

Answer (score 2):

If you have them both connected to the same network, then you are in luck. There is a little program called [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) that will do this for you. Requires a little configuration, but there is one gotcha to look out for.

When you set it up and say that, for example, the laptop is to the right of the desktop... make sure to also tell it that the desktop is to the left of the laptop. Otherwise, your mouse can go from the desktop to the laptop and can't get back!

Comment: Synergy is a great tool, but just to clarify: it won't make your other computer a second display, it'll just let you move the mouse back and forth between the two displays, and you only need 1 keyboard. You're still using 2 computers at once.

Comment: +1 for interesting solution, but it wasn't exactly what OP asked for

Comment: That may be true, but that does give you an interesting tradeoff. You lose the ability to move windows from one monitor to the other, and in return you can have the laptop grinding away at something, and mouse back to the desktop and use it with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanh/archive/2004/03/07/85668.aspxhttp://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanh/archive/2004/03/07/85668.aspx) blog post, you can use [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/) for this purpose.
If you don't mind dropping the $40, that is.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this webpage from Alternativeto.com...it lists the (mostly) free alternatives to Maxivista...as good of a list as you're gonna get...

http://alternativeto.net/desktop/maxivista/

Also, check out [QSynergy](http://www.volker-lanz.de/en/software/qsynergy/) (better GUI) and [Synergy+](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/) (Although, now Synergy and Synergy+ have merged...