# Use Laptop A with windows 7 as a monitor for Laptop B with windows xp pro & broken screen

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, display, lcd

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Use laptop A's LCD as secondary monitor for laptop B](https://superuser.com/questions/129249/use-laptop-as-lcd-as-secondary-monitor-for-laptop-b)
>   [Can I use a laptop as Second monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/182218/can-i-use-a-laptop-as-second-monitor)
>   [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer)

I currently have two laptops.

Laptop A - Sony Vaio Model: PCG 71312L OS: Windows 7

Laptop B - Toshiba Satelite A105 OS: Windows XP Pro

Laptop B's monitor has damaged and does not function. However, it can output screen on an external monitor as I tested it with an regular PC desktop monitor.

I have been desperately searching for a way to use my laptop A as an external monitor for laptop B. Or ultimately what I like to achieve is to be able to operate laptop B without using another external monitor as I cannot afford to buy one.

Any creative way to achieve my ultimate goal would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you won't be able to use the monitor from Laptop A as an external monitor for Laptop B directly.

If however you are able to use a regular external monitor on Laptop B for a short time you could setup Remote Desktop (right click on my computer, properties, advanced system settings, remote (tab), select allow connects. You might also want to adjust the users that can log in via these means.

Once this is done you should be able to log into Laptop B by opening the start menu and typing remote (in the windows 7 search bar), "Remote Desktop Connection" should be the first search result. Use that, type in the name of Laptop B then you'll need to log into it.

Another option is to setup a VNC server on laptop B and a viewer on Laptop A. I use Ultra VNC. This is a reasonably simple option for controlling (and seeing whats on the screen of) the second laptop, but you can run into some quirks here and there.

Comment: +1 for Remote Desktop suggestion. Borrowing a screen for a short time to enable it is the easiest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a paid solution called **[MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/)**, but that's pretty much the only solution out there...

> Multi Monitor Software
>
> MaxiVista turns any spare Desktop, Laptop or Netbook PC into a dual monitor for your primary computer. No extra multi monitor hardware is required. Simply extend program windows across multiple screens as if it were one big monitor. Increase your productivity by using multiple monitors.

Comment: No, it's not. [SpaceDesk](http://spacedesk.ph) is free and works well.

Comment: @niutech: I wasn't aware of this solution almost 5 years ago - if it works well, would you consider writing an answer about it?

Comment: It works well, I am using it now. But I cannot write an answer because it is a duplicate question.

Comment: @niutech forgive me, when I followed up on your comment, the link took me directly to my answer, I had forgotten this was closed. Perhaps on the original question? It looks really solid, I'll have to keep this in mind for the future.