# Is it possible to use a laptop mornitor as an extended display of another machine?

Tags: laptop, extended-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer)

I have a powerful desktop PC and a weak laptop :)

My need is that I want to use the weaker machine as an extended display of the strong one. Is it possible to do so? If it is, please guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: Using VGA connector

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer). The usual answer is Synergy.

Answer (score 2):

Doubtful, unless your laptop has an appropriate *input* connector.

Comment: Most of the laptops have `out-display` connector and I have hardly seen any which has `in-display` connector

Answer (score 0):

Using the network as the connection, you could set up vncserver on the desktop console and run vncviewer on the laptop.

Comment: This'll duplicate the display, not extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Use VGA connector. There will two socket attached to one cable. Socket is like Monitor Pin.
Attach one side to your laptop and other to your desktop and you will be able to see your desktop screen either on your laptop or on both laptop and desktop.

It's same process as you attach projector to your laptop.

Comment: That's to opposite of what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Sirex What is OP stands for?

Comment: @Nam Gi VU - "Original poster" - the guy who asked the question.

Comment: how is it opposite of OP wanted?

Comment: what you describe wont work. Most (nearly all) laptops have a video *out* not a video *in*. You can display the laptop's display on another monitor (or projector) but you cant (as the OP wanted) display a desktop's output on a laptop.