# Can I connect an Xbox console to a laptop monitor through an HDMI port that supports only video?

Tags: laptop, hdmi, xbox360

I want to know if it is possible to connect an Xbox 360 console to the monitor of a laptop. I have searched about this and I have found out that it might be able to be done through an HDMI port that would connect both the video and the audio.

My laptop has an HDMI port, I have looked in the manual and it says that the HDMI port "Supports high definition digital video connections", but nothing about sound, so I presume that the port does not support sound, only video.

My question is, can I still connect the console for video output and use headphones that I connect directly to the console itself for audio ?

I am not familiar neither with the Xbox console nor with how the HDMI port works so I am asking to be sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a laptop mornitor as an extended display of another machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/228813/is-it-possible-to-use-a-laptop-mornitor-as-an-extended-display-of-another-machin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your laptop HDMI only supports audio and video **out**, not in.  It is no different than a VGA, DVI, or DisplayPort connection.  You will not be able connect your XBox to your laptop's monitor.