# How can I connect a desktop CPU to a laptop screen without an external monitor?

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer)

The laptop works fine but is slow. The desktop works fine doesn't have a monitor.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not looking for high performance graphics, just access to the PC then you could try using [VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Really you need to fix up one of the systems to be the good one ;)
Anyway, yes, like other have said you'll need a video input on the laptop, another way would be to network the machines and use VNC, run your hard-core resource hungry apps on the desktop whilst viewing them on the laptop, but this requires a high speed network between the two or you'll suffer a lot of lag.

Answer (score 0):

You're laptop likely has no video input port, so you  cant pipe the desktop output to it. You might be able to run 2d apps over vnc from the desktop, but i wouldn't expect much from it.