# Using a Netbook to create a Dual Monitor Setup

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, netbook, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer)

I bought a Netbook, and so far I love it. However, I'd like to get a bit more utility out of it. When I'm at home it just sits on my dresser, not being productive at all. I was thinking that I could use it as a secondary monitor for my main laptop. What software and hardware would be necessary for a setup such as this? Even though the screen is small I figure I could use it to augment various tasks. I figure it'd be neat to have two webpages open simultaneously.

It's an Asus Eee running Windows 7 stater, while my main laptop is a Sony Vaio running Windows 7 Home Premium. Both have Ubuntu 10.04 installed, however I'd like to stay on the Windows side for this.

**Edit**

I did a little more research and it looks like I may be able to do it with simply a VGA cable. Before I run out and buy one, I'd like to make sure I'm interpreting [this](http://www.netbooklink.com/accessories/external-lcd-monitors/how-to-connect-an-external-lcd-monitor-to-a-netbook) right.

Comment: see also: http://superuser.com/questions/129221/dual-monitor-tool-like-maxivista-but-free-opensource

Comment: Concerning your edit: You can extend your desktop of either your netbook or your laptop with a vga cable, but for that you need an extra screen. It's not possible to share for instance the screen on your netbook with your laptop using a vga cable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/), it allows you to move your mouse between multiple computers, its not exactly like adding a monitor, but it does give you the ability to use both computers and only use one single interface to do so, so it is similar to the concept of multi-monitor, but processes on both monitors do not need to compete for resources, though you cannot move windows between the monitors.

From the website:

```
* Move your mouse easily between computers
* Requires nothing other than existing ethernet
* Copy and paste between your computers
* No need to press any buttons (unlike KVM)
* You can still use multiple monitors on the same computer
* Lock the mouse to one screen
```

Also a bonus, it is open source, so there is no cost to use it.

Comment: Sharing a keyboard and mouse is totally not the same thing as sharing a monitor.

Comment: I am aware of that and I made it very clear in my post. I also gave the reason why it can be better or worse, depending on what the user may want. His concern was not necessarily a dual monitor, but making use of the device. This offers an alternative that is perfectly viable based on his criteria.

Answer (score 2):

[MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/) is what you need:

> MaxiVista is a Windows software
>   utility with four major functions:
>
> - The **Extended screen mode** enables you
>     to extend your primary PC's desktop to
>     up to three extra PCs.
> - The **remote
>     control mode** allows you to operate
>     multiple computers from a single mouse
>     and keyboard.
> - The **clipboard
>     synchronization** feature allows you to
>     share clipboard contents with all
>     other computers.
> - The **mirror mode**
>     duplicates the screen contents of one
>     computer to another computer using any
>     network connection.