# How to extend a screen over an network computer?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer)
>   [What is a free/open source tool to allow me to control another computer or use it as a second monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/129221/what-is-a-free-open-source-tool-to-allow-me-to-control-another-computer-or-use-i)

What software could I use in order to use a laptop as a 2nd screen? the laptop would be connected to the network over wifi.

```
Maxivista : not free. 
ZoneScreen : only clone your display do not allow to expand. 
ThighVNC : same thing.
```

I'm using windows 7 64bits.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a free/open source tool to allow me to control another computer or use it as a second monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/129221/what-is-a-free-open-source-tool-to-allow-me-to-control-another-computer-or-use-i) and/or [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer/15255#15255)

Comment: If you don't like the existing answers on those questions, and would like new/different ones, consider gathering some Rep. and placing a [bounty](http://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: To be fair MaxiVista is $40 (not millions). And it does a great job.