# Use old laptop as additional screen with Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop, display, extended-desktop

In the past, I've used [Maxivista](http://www.maxivista.com/) to use a laptop's screen as an additional monitor for my primary computer. It works great, and I'm quite pleased with it.

However, I've now upgraded to Windows 8, and Maxivista doesn't support that version of Windows. I've done some searching and have not been able to find any utility like Maxivista that supports Windows 8. The only Maxivista-like utility I've found is "Zonescreen," which also does not support Windows 8. Does such a utility exist for Windows 8?

Note that I am not talking about desktop mirroring or a software KVM. I've found apps like VNC and Synergy that allow you to do those things, but I'm looking to extend my desktop.

I've searched here on Superuser.com and I see quite a few questions about this, all related to Windows 7 and earlier.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."

Comment: In the end, it's the same question as: [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer/15255#15255), perhaps consider placing a bounty on that one requesting newer answers.

Comment: @techie007, the Windows 8 constraint on my question means that valid answers to the question you linked to would not be valid in my case. And, in fact, there are a number of valid answers to that question that don't work for Windows 8. But thanks for the link anyway!

Comment: just because the answers aren't satisfactory doesn't make it a different question, hence why I suggest putting a bounty on it for newer answers. Actually, I've got points to burn so I'll put one on it.

Comment: But without the Windows 8 constraint on the *question*, it seems unlikely that I will get useful answers to *my* question, which is indeed constrained to Windows 8... ?

Comment: will mark as dupe now since the other question has a bounty + I've tagged with [tag:windows-8]