# Use displays on Linux machine to extend Windows Desktop

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, windows-8.1, vnc

I have a Linux server with two monitors standing next to my Windows 8.1 machine. Since I won't be actually interfacing with server too much I would like to use its two monitors to extend my Windows desktop most of the time. I am thinking that getting my Windows machine to make use of 2 virtual monitors that stream their content over some remote desktop protocol to 2 viewers on my Linux machine. I basically need a free (DIY if needed) alternative to MaxiVista that has decent performance (so no ZeroDesktop). I have tried TighVNC with DFMirage but I could not get it to work right, it merely displayed the content of all my monitors in one scrollable window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you connect the monitors to your Windows 8.1 machine and then remote into the server as needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer), [What is a free/open source tool to allow me to control another computer or use it as a second monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/129221/what-is-a-free-open-source-tool-to-allow-me-to-control-another-computer-or-use-i)

Comment: @joeqwerty my windows PC only has a physical connector for an external display