# Use Surface Pro 3 as second or extended monitor instead using it as a computer?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

Particularly how to use Surface Pro 3 as a 2nd monitor only. not as a surface pro itself. i.e. I have a laptop and use surface pro as a second monitor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Well, Surface Pro 3 is not really an laptop per se. Why so strict? lol

Comment: We don't like duplicate questions here, and the make/shape of your device doesn't matter in this case.  When you tried the existing suggestions on the question I marked as a (possible) dupe, what were your results?

Comment: Hum... Maybe ppl should think search terms less like creating a class and not duplicating them, i think its rather the opposite. As long as answer is meaningful it should be perfectly suitable. View counts tells everything

Comment: I'm not sure what you're driving at?  There's nothing wrong with the answer given here, and it would be just as suitable if it was added to the question I marked as possible dupe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the free app [Splashtop](http://www.splashtop.com/) on the surface and install the Splashtop streamer on your laptop.

Now you can connect to your surface.

Comment: How exactly it works?? I dont really understand. May I have a more detailed instruction on this?

Comment: I've never used it myself, but you can download the App und Streamer here: http://www.splashtop.com/downloads and here are some manuals: https://support-splashtoppersonal.splashtop.com/forums

Comment: This is remote desktop control software though. How it related to extend as 2nd monitor?

Comment: This is a youtube video for splashtop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldb0RvmXzsA