# Laptop as second monitor to Desktop

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I would like to ask, how do I extend my laptop (running Windows 10) as a second monitor to my main desktop (also Windows 10). Preferably, I'd like to have a free option over a cord, although wireless would still be acceptable.

The graphics card on my desktop is an Nvidia GeForce GTX 950.

Comment: Laptop monitors cannot be used as a second monitor.

Comment: Related: [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor). Short answer: no built-in way, maybe 3rd party utilities (do note that some of the links/advice in the other question may be outdated).

Answer (score 0):

Laptop displays are just designed to be output for the laptop mobo it is setup into.

Probabaly the only "workaround" if you want to call it that would be to setup a Remote Desktop or VNC type client / server configuration. Might work alright if you use it in a home network solution. That way you share your screen so to speak with the laptop display. Then your laptop runs and operates as usual.