# Any way to connect external monitor to laptop without cable?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

i was pretty excited about connecting my second monitor to my laptop but i noticed my laptop does not have VGA input and monitor does not have HDMI. Is there any way (like LAN-based thing) that i can connect this monitor to my laptop?

This external monitor is used with desktop PC which i have available but you know its not that powerful as my laptop so i wanted to game on 2 monitors. I was thinking about something like i turn on desktop PC and laptop and somwhow connect them with some soft or whatever. I will probably go buy correction (convertor) tomorrow but just wondering.

Sorry for noobish question really. And thanks for answers :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 no it's not. This question is about connecting a *monitor* over ethernet.

Comment: Yes you can connect projectors / monitors over ethernet, but this solution will be way more expensive than a 15 - 25$ converter.

Comment: You say: "I was thinking about something like i turn on desktop PC and laptop and somwhow connect them with some soft or whatever" which his exactly what the duplicate I suggested offers solutions for.  Otherwise, unless you have some magic VGA/HDMI to Ethernet adaptor in hand that you failed to mention, you're going to need hardware, and if you need hardware, then you might as well just go get the converter you plan on getting.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you would be satisfied with a USB monitor adapter. Here's a [random example of one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0086359SG).

Note that with such adapters, you'll generally get much better performance to get a USB 3.0 adapter (and obviously use it with a USB 3.0 port).

A weird alternative is to consider using [Synergy](http://symless.com/synergy/). It is not at all a means of connecting a secondary display, but I indirectly use it for exactly that. Synergy lets you share a keyboard and mouse across many machines. So you can put another computer beside your laptop (such as another laptop) and use it with the main computer. This is incredibly helpful for certain use cases and may not fit for you.