# Is it possible to use a laptop with thunderbolt 3 as external monitor? Considering an external gpu can be used, can an 'internal' gpu be used too?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu

I'm looking into buying a new laptop and a lot of laptops I'm looking at have one or more thunderbolt 3 connections. Suddenly I had a thought. External gpus are more and more common nowadays. And I was wondering if it's possible to connect a normal internal gpu inside a desktop to a laptop using a thunderbolt 3 port and use the laptop as external monitor?

I don't know how the connection between e-gpu and laptop works, but one way or another it should spit out a raw video signal and return that to the laptop. Isn't that exactly the same as a normal internal gpu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor/738821#738821

Comment: @Moab That question is 10 years old. The market and technologies have changed a lot since then. Including the arrival of external gpus. My question is specifically asking if it's possible to attach a laptop via thunderbolt to an internal gpu and use it as external gpu just like one can attach an external gpu.

Comment: @Landcross - The fact the question is 10 years old does not take away from the fact it's still an accurate answer.  Most desktop GPUs don't even support Thunderbolt.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not talking about thunderbolt support on the gpu side. That's just displayport, just like those e-gpu boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The commercial app [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) lets you run one app across two PCs with one keyboard and mouse, as do [Open Source alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/synergy/).