# Use laptop as second monitor

Tags: windows-10, laptop, macbook, manjaro

I have a old macbook running Manjaro and a PC running windows 10. Is there any way to use the laptop as a second screen for my main computer?

EDIT: Please do not mark as duplicate or link the other thread because the solution to that thread requires installing an unsigned driver and does not solve my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor)

Comment: @gronostaj the answer for that question, ZoneScreen, requires disabling secure boot (I think)

Comment: The accepted answer is not the only answer on the linked answer. The judgment of duplicate is not based on the answer but the question. Yours is the same question. Yours is duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Synergy](http://symless.com/synergy). It is not free ($29), but it is a one-time lifetime purchase, and it it totally worth it. It works on every major operating system, and allows seamless connection between multiple devices.

Comment: As my laptop is pretty slow, that wouldn't work pretty well. Also, there's barrier, which is a free fork of synergy.

Comment: I have never heard of that! I’ll check it out.