# Using laptop‘s monitor as a gaming monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, gaming, usb-c

I have a huawei matebook x pro with a screen resolution of 3000x2000 and I want to use it as a gaming monitor, the question is : can I use my huawei’ laptop as a monitor for gaming by connecting it to the gaming pc?? Or the latency will be high? Since there are software that can do it like miracast but the latency is so high, so is there a way to use the laptop’s screen as a gaming monitor or it isn’t possible.

Thx

Comment: Not without removing the panel from the laptop, and finding a device to connect it to a HDMI or Display Port cable.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

[Some solutions exist](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor) that enable use of another computer as an additional screen, but they will involve latency unacceptable for gaming.