# Connect a laptop as a secondary monitor via HDMI port of a graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, external-display, laptop-display

My desktop has a NVIDIA GT 730. It has both VGA and HDMI port.
My desktop monitor is connected in VGA port of the graphics card.
**Now, can I connect my old Laptop as a secondary screen via a HDMI cable in the HDMI port of the Graphics Card of my desktop?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using a HDMI cable unless it support HDMI Input. Usually you should have only HDMI output, not input.

But if both laptops have wifi, windows 10 will allow to stream output over wifi. You need to have wifi adapters but connection to same wifi is not required. Make sure both laptops have wifi, and in primary laptop go to System > Settings > Projecting and enable it. On monitor like laptop, hit Win+P and choose Connect, then find your device choose primary laptop. Now you can hit win+p again in primary laptop and choose either duplicate or extended mode.