# Wireless Monitor for PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I am developing 1 project where I want to control Devices from My PC. I have application where I have created all the graphic for the same. I have configured this application for Dual Monitor . But I have only 1 monitor. I want to access 2nd Monitor wirelessly on Windows tablet. From PC 1 user is Controlling the device at the same time another user also control devices from Tablet ( 2 monitor )
Is there any way to full fill this type of requirement.
Also used RDP protocol , but when I connect my tablet to PC through RDP PC got locked. So this is also not working for me.

Comment: If you need More Details then let me know.

Comment: So you want two monitors with simultaneous independent input on each?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes.

Comment: So, is your question about controlling devices, or about connecting a tablet monitor as a secondary monitor for your computer? Please EDIT your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

See if this works for you?  Windows has an option for connecting to a wireless diaplay.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[SPACEDESK](https://spacedesk.net/)**, it looks like Spacedesk App will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks For Answering . Can i able to control from Both screen at the same time ?

Comment: In general, yes.
The second Windows display on the client device (viewer) = regular iOS/Android/Windows application.
The device retains its functionality.

Try it yourself and see its documentation, Spacedesk is commonly free